# error c2084 on all my methods but each method only has one body

Tags: c++

Only one of my classes are having this problem, it keeps saying error c2084, see previous definition which takes me to the same spot where the error is.

Here's my .h file

```
//PersonalInfo header file

#ifndef PERSONALINFO_H
#define PERSONALINFO_H

#include <string>

class PersonalInfo {

private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int age;
    std::string phoneNumber;

public:
    //default constructor
    PersonalInfo();

    //copy constructor
    PersonalInfo(const PersonalInfo&) = default;

    //getters
    std::string getFirstName();
    std::string getLastName();
    int getAge();
    std::string getPhoneNumber();

    //setters
    void setFirstName(std::string name);
    void setLastName(std::string name);
    void setAge(int num);
    void setPhoneNumber(std::string number);
};

#include "PersonalInfo.cpp"
#endif
```

Here's my .cpp, as you can see, they are only defined once but the error says they are defined already.
This website is making me add more info to post but there is no more info on this error to give so now im just typing until it lets me post

```
#include "PersonalInfo.h"

//default constructor
PersonalInfo::PersonalInfo() {
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    age = -1;
    phoneNumber = "";
}

//getters
std::string PersonalInfo::getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

std::string PersonalInfo::getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

int PersonalInfo::getAge() {
    return age;
}

std::string PersonalInfo::getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

//setters
void PersonalInfo::setFirstName(std::string name) {
    firstName = name;
}

void PersonalInfo::setLastName(std::string name) {
    lastName = name;
}

void PersonalInfo::setAge(int num) {
    age = num;
}

void PersonalInfo::setPhoneNumber(std::string number) {
    phoneNumber = number;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `#include "PersonalInfo.cpp"` at the end of the `.h` file. It's a mistake, don't do it

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `#include "PersonalInfo.cpp"` at the end of the `.h` file. You're creating a circular include chain between two files and it makes everything duplicated. Your `.cpp` files should `#include` your `.h` files, not the other way around.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're right, although I've come across with some freaky code golfing like projects that did unapropiate and nonsensical things like this. Editing it now. Thank you.